# How to find mean position of white pixels on video stream OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've searched this question up and found multiple stack overflow posts about this but they weren't helpful. I've written code to find the white pixels in an image and then draw a circle around them, but the problem is there are multiple white pixels in an image so what happens is that the circle moves rapidly from one pixel to another because all the pixels are white. I want to find the average position of all the white pixels so that the circle stays consistent.

Here's my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



URL = "http://192.168.1.104:81/stream"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(URL)

def mask():
    # for masking white
    sensitivity = 20
    lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 255 - sensitivity])
    upper_white = np.array([255, sensitivity, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
    return result




def coord_of_white():
    Y, X = np.where(np.all(frame == [255, 255, 255], axis=2))
    zipped = np.column_stack((X, Y))
    for points in zipped:
        return cv2.circle(frame, points, 20, (0, 0, 255))  # displays circles at the coordinates of white pixels



while True:
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        coord_of_white()
        cv2.imshow("ESP32 CAM", cv2.flip(frame, 0))
        cv2.imshow("ESP32 CAM MASK", cv2.flip(mask(), 0))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: First off, your `coord_of_white` should not have a `return` statement in it -- that's just going to draw the first circle and stop. Try deleting that first and you'll see circles on every white pixel. Once that's in place you can decide how to proceed, but I don't think averaging is going to do what you want, what if there are two white pixels on opposite sides of the image? The circle will be halfway between them...

Comment: thanks for your comment, I removed the return statement and as you said there are now multiple circles around each white pixel. I think averaging the position is the best option, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do and what kind of input you expect. But in general you may want to cluster them somehow before averaging, so that you can accommodate images with "different groups" of white pixels.